# How do I make PWA-support for a local website?

Tags: node.js, https, raspberry-pi, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a cross-browser and cross-platform [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_applications) for a camera slider. The idea is that a Raspberry Pi is serving a web interface for controlling this and also serves as an access point so it can be used without an Internet connection.

But since PWAs need the HTTPS protocol I don't know how I can serve my web application over HTTPS in a local network. Certificates are bought for domain names and not for a local IP address.

I do not want my customers to have to accept an "unsecure" private certificate every time before they can use my application.

Is there even a solution for my problem?

Comment: HTTPS is a core requirement. No other options.

Comment: Use something like LetsEncrypt, there is node packages to handle it, or you can use a reverse proxy in front, there is also services like cloudflare, which you prob will want to use anyway, if your hosting from home. now.sh is also an option.